# Setting up help for a Delphi app

Tags: delphi

What's the best way to set up help (specifically [HTML Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670068(VS.85).aspx)) for a Delphi application?  I can see several options, all of which has disadvantages.  Specifically:

1. I could set HelpContext in the forms designer wherever appropriate, but then I'm stuck having to track numbers instead of symbolic constants.
2. I could set HelpContext programmatically.  Then I can use symbolic constants, but I'd have more code to keep up with, and I couldn't easily check the text DFMs to see which forms still need help.
3. I could set HelpKeyword, but since that does a keyword lookup (like Application.HelpKeyword) rather than a topic jump (like Application.HelpJump), I'd have to make sure that each of my help pages has a unique, non-changing, top-level keyword; this seems like extra work.  (And there are HelpKeyword-related VCL bugs like [this](http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=31175) and [this](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=69784).)
4. I could set HelpKeyword, set an Application.OnHelp handler to convert HelpKeyword requests to HelpJump requests so that I can assign help by topic ID instead of keyword lookup, and add code such as my own help viewer (based on [HelpScribble's code](http://www.helpscribble.com/delphi-bcb.html)) that fixes the VCL bugs and lets HelpJump work with anchors.  By this point, though, I feel like I'm working against the VCL rather than with it.

**Which approach did you choose for your app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create the help file, which gets the help topic ID, and then go around the forms and set their HelpContext values to them. Since the level of maintenance needed is very low - the form is unlikely to change help file context unless something major happens - this works just fine.

Comment: For now, at least, I like keeping our code to a minimum, so I'm accepting this solution, but the other answers have good information as well.

Answer (score 6):

When I first started researching how to do this several years ago, I first got the "All About help files in Borland Delphi" tutorial from: http://www.ec-software.com/support_tutorials.html

In that document, the section "Preparing a help file for context sensitive help" (which in my version of the document starts on page 28). It describes a nice numbering scheme you can use to organize your numbers into sections, e.g. Starting with 100000 for your main form and continuing with 101000 or 110000 for each secondary form, etc.

But then I wanted to use descriptive string IDs instead of numbers for my Help topics. I started using THelpRouter, which is part of EC Software's free Help Suite at: http://www.ec-software.com/downloads_delphi.html

But then I settled on a Help tool that supported string ID's directly for topics (I use Dr. Explain: http://www.drexplain.com/) so now I simply use HelpJump, e.g.:

> Application.HelpJump('UGQuickStart');

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

We use symbolic constants. Yes, it is a bit more work, but it pays off. Especially because some of our dialogs are dynamically built and sometimes require different help IDs.

Answer (score 1):

We use Help&Manual - its a wonderful tool, outputting almost any format of stuff you could want, doc, rtf, html, pdf - all from the same source. It will even read in (or paste from rtf (eg MSWord). It uses topic ID's (strings) which I just keep a list of and I manually put each one into a form (or class) as it suits me. Sounds difficult but trust me you'll spend far longer hating the wrong authouring tool. I spent years finding it!
Brian

Comment: We're using Help & Manual too, but how do you get your forms to use the topic IDs?  Delphi's HelpKeyword doesn't seem to use topic IDs; do you programmatically set HelpContext to a topic ID's number, or do you do something else?