# including help file in Delphi app

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, helpfile

I have help file "help.hap" I add him to app by typing his name in app properti under HelpFile. Then I add

```
procedure TForm1.Pomoc1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Application.HelpContext(0);
end;
```

But I get error

> no context-sensitive help installed

WTF I just add it right?

Comment: What kind of help file is that? As well as setting the HelpFile property of Application, you need to make sure you have an appropriate help viewer for that type of help file. Do you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hello again :)
 No, I don't. Damn it. could you suggest some think?

Comment: BTW. I'm using Delphi XE2. - maybe with that program I can make help file?

Comment: What type of help file is it?

Comment: If you don't tell us what format the help file is, how are we supposed to suggest a help viewer? And no, Delphi doesn't come with a help authoring tool; there are free, shareware,  and commercial ones available. Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658193/setting-up-help-for-a-delphi-app), which I found looking at the "Related" list to the right of your question (it's the third related link). Look at the answers there; there's a long one that contains links to lots of articles on writing and using help in Delphi applications.

Comment: The question explains why Heffernan has such a wild look on his avatar.

Comment: See here at Torry's : [Help Author Pro](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=3079). Seems that MaxComponents is out of business. If you still have that tool, export the help file to a format that suits XE2.

Comment: If so, follow Rob's suggestion and you should be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Help.hap* is the name of your Help Author Pro project file. It is no more a help file than your *.dpr* Delphi project file is an executable program.

You can use your help-authoring tool to generate documentation in several different formats, including HTML and RTF. Generate an actual help file, such as *help.hlp* or *help.chm*.

Comment: And then include either WinhelpViewer or HtmlhelpViewer in your project

Comment: I'd advise .chm as the newer Windows versions (Vista and up) no longer support .hlp out-of-the-box and require a separate tool to be installed to view .hlp files.